# Installing git on shared hosting - ./configure: no such file or directory

Tags: linux, git, bash, github, ssh

Im trying to install git on shared hosting - (via SSH, `gcc --version` returns number) I downloaded the lasted git from GitHub: `wget https://github.com/git/git/archive/v1.8.4.2.tar.gz` then extracted it to a folder: `tar zxvf v1.8.4.2` and navigated to the git folder: `cd git-v1.8.4.2`.

then tried to install it: `./configure prefix=/home/$USER --with-curl --with-expat`.

[image]

the command returned `bash: ./cofigure.ac: No such file or directory`. its seems like there is no configure file? why? there is another file to configure?

i saw there is a file named `configure.ac` and started it. not worked:

[image: git shared hosting configure.ac]

what is the problem? how I can configure git before installing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just type

```
make configure
```

to create the configure file.